# Parse integers separated by spaces rather than line by line - C++

Tags: java, c++, parsing

I am reading from a text file, and I need to be able to access each integer similar to how Java uses nextInt(). Right now, if I have an ifstream called "input" and a variable "x" of type INT, `input >> x` will ignore all the spaces in the line and give me one large integer, rather than just giving me the first integer in the line.

For example, if my text file looks like this:

```
5 67 8
12 3 4
```

When I say `input >> x`, x now has the value "5678" instead of just '5', and then '67' the next time I call it.

How can I parse ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mistaken. `operator>>` does not work like that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited my post to better show how my text file looks. This is how the parsing is working for me.. I am printing my numbers to check and that it how it's working for some reason.

Comment: No, that's still not how `operator>>` works.

Comment: 1. Why do you tag `java` when the question is about C++? 2. `cin` doesn't read through spaces

Comment: Show more of your code please.

Comment: C++ is not Java

Answer (score 0):

mgl@mgl:~/Documents$ cat int_file.log

45 20 12 45 21 25

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> words;
    ifstream in("int_file.log");
    int word;
    while( in >> word)
    words.push_back(word);

for(int i = 0; i < words.size();i++)
cout << words[i] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

## include

## include

The following code works as expected:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream input ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    int x, y, z;

    input >> x;
    input >> y;
    input >> z;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << " z = " << z << std::endl;
}
```